# how to change the UIImagePickerController crop frame

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

when opening working with an UIImagePickerController and setting  allowsImageEditing = YES; there is a default cropping frame that is 320x320. In my case, I would like to setup that cropping frame to 320x240 for images that are landscape, and 240x320 for images that are portrait. However, I haven't been able to find a way to change that 320x320 frame that is used when editing /cropping a photo. Has any of you found a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

You have to implement it your self.

The picker only performs 320x320 cropping.

So instead set

allowsImageEditing = NO;

Now you will get the full image back. Then you will have to create a view/view controller that will crop to the proportions you desire.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [ShittyImageCrop](https://github.com/budidino/ShittyImageCrop). It's good for cropping to a specific aspect ratio. In your case, present it with aspect ratio 4:3 (or 3:4 in landscape) like this:

```
let cropVC = ShittyImageCropVC(frame: (self.navigationController?.view.frame)!, image: imageToCrop, aspectWidth: 4, aspectHeight: 3)
self.navigationController?.present(cropVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After that you can use some other code to just scale it to desired resolution (320x240 or 240x320).

Answer (score 2):

This is the more recent answer with the necessary manual cropping code: [Manual Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101576/1627959)

There is still no escaping the hard work.