# iPhone:How to implement "move and scale" functionality for image fetched from photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photo-gallery

As shown in the following figure I want to implement "move and scale" functionality for the image fetched from the photo library.

If you have any idea or code then provide me.

[image]

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 7):

See this [answer by Jane Sales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605385/591951)

From The answer for this question [Set dimensions for UIImagePickerController “move and scale” cropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041732/set-dimensions-for-uiimagepickercontroller-move-and-scale-cropbox)

> The solution I recommend is to disable editing for the image picker
>   and handle it yourself. For instance, I put the image in a scrollable,
>   zoomable image view. On top of the image view is a fixed position
>   "crop guide view" that draws the crop indicator the user sees.
>   Assuming the guide view has properties for the visible rect (the part
>   to keep) and edge widths (the part to discard) you can get the
>   cropping rectangle like so.

Here is link for [Re-sizing + UIImage](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

1) [Link for Cropping a UIImage](http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/)

2) [Another link](http://maybelost.com/2010/11/cropping-a-uiimage-on-iphone/)

3) [More things to do with UIImage](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html)

Comment: The link you provided "answer by Jane Sales" uses delegate method of UIImage but I want this kind of image from photo library. then how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely late, but hopefully it'll help.

In the UIImagePickerController Delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` the "moved" and "scaled" image is accessed through the `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` key like this

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
     UIImage *img = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

 // Do what you need to with that image

 }
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
```

Then in the delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(!chosenImage) {
        chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2, be sure `pickerController.allowsEditing = true` is added to the method that accesses your photos.

Then, create the following method with the two qualifying "if statements". The "if statements" will cover two different scenarios: 1) the user edits the photo - `.editedImage` OR 2) the user did not edit the photo - `.originalImage`.

For this method to work properly, be sure to place the `.editedImage` "if statement" first. I don't know why this is so, but I had to.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {

        imageView.image = editedImage

    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

        imageView.image = image
    }


    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this answer only if others are not working.... :)

In [ZBar project](http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/zbar/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg) there are some sample applications, which takes the pic of Barcode. It allows to Move and Scale the image. I havnt looked at the code. But you can try as your last option.