# UIImagePickerController custom editing mode

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, customization, subclass

I try to implement custom editing into my UIImagePickerController. I wrote a drawing view subclass of UIView.

And now I want to add one of my UIDrawView as the editing view for the UIImagePickerController. Is there a way to implement something like this?

I heard that the UIImagePickerController is a UINavigationController. So could I make a subclass of UIImagePickerController and push an UIDrawView object into the imagePicker when the user took a photo?

If possible, which class methods should I inherit from UIImagePickerController?

---

Thanks for any help! With kind regards   – Julian

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041732/set-dimensions-for-uiimagepickercontroller-move-and-scale-cropbox Useful link here.. :)