# image picker controller not able to change the default crop square size after clicking image from iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

[image showing the imagepickercontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZSUt.jpg)

As shown in this figure, that square position is not changing or resizing when i take picture from camera but it is working from gallery. Please help to how to change the position of crop square to go to required part of image.

the code used is given below

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let  image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        print(image.size)
        let croppedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        print(croppedImage ?? "")
        let cropRect = (info[UIImagePickerControllerCropRect]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        print(cropRect?.size ?? "")
        let _ = UIImage.cropImage(image: image, toRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, w: self.imgProfile.bounds.width, h: self.imgProfile.bounds.width))
        print(image.size)
        self.imgProfile.image = croppedImage
        profileImgUpdated = true

    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openCamera(){
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}

func openPhotoLibrary() {
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using right now to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift 4.2** `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]` is depricated, try with,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imgProfile.image = editedImage
    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imgProfile.image = image
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

To enable editing,

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.allowsEditing = true
```

Comment: this is not helpful i was asking for solution for the cropped square in image to move but it wasnt moving when i am taking picture through camera

Comment: For enabling cropping please use `let picker = UIImagePickerController() picker.allowsEditing = true` and make use of `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.cropRect`

Comment: I have cropping but as u see in above image I am not able to change crop square to other part of image

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041732/set-dimensions-for-uiimagepickercontroller-move-and-scale-cropbox/9101576#9101576