# Create custom UIImagePickerController to set aspect ratio of camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Stack Overflow maybe has 1000 threads addressing and re-addressing cropping images on iOS; many of which contains answers claiming to work just like Instagram (my guess is they never open Instagram). So instead of simply using the word Instagram, let me describe the functionalities of what I am trying to do:

I want to create CustomUIImagePickerController such that:

- **CAMERA:** I can either set the exact dimension of the image that the camera takes; or on the very next screen (i.e. retake/use image) have a custom rectangle that the user can move to crop the image just taken.
- **GALLERY:** (same as above:) set the dimensions of the frame that user will use to crop the image.

So far on SO one answer comes close: the answer points to https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker.

But the crucial problem with that project is that it only works with **gallery**. It does not work with **camera**.

So lastly, if you look at the Instagram app for iOS-7, it takes complete control of the picture taking experience. How do I do that? I don’t want to have my users go through the whole standard iOS UIImagePickerController experience and **then** on top of that have them go through my own cropper just to load an image. That’s simply terrible user experience. How many steps or screens does one need to take or load a picture? Right? I know I can't be the only developer who would love to solve this problem. I don’t mind being the one to find the solution and then share it with the world. But presently I don’t even know where to start?

Does anyone have any ideas where I might start?

BTW: the following are not answers:

- [how to change the UIImagePickerController crop frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998706/how-to-change-the-uiimagepickercontroller-crop-frame)
- [Set dimensions for UIImagePickerController "move and scale" cropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041732/set-dimensions-for-uiimagepickercontroller-move-and-scale-cropbox?lq=1)

Comment: Disclaimer: I've never used Instagram but what you're describing is similar to what I needed recently.  The latest version of [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor) allows the user to crop an image free hand or by a pre-defined aspect ratio.  This was a good starting point for me where I merged aspects of several other projects into this one for a better user experience.